# Apache Syncope Depends on Maven? What is maven for in this context?

Tags: ansible, apache2, jenkins, maven, identity-management

> fwiw: I did not come into this looking for another CI/CD tool. I came
>   into this looking for an IAM tool (and I found Syncope). When Syncope
>   install documentation called for Maven that's when the confusion arose.
>   If Maven would add value to my CI/CD pipeline I am not against this. But
>   note, I wasn't looking for that when I went to the Syncope documentation.
>
> If I can use syncope without having to deal with Maven after that it is
>   probably best. Unless I can tell how Maven will help in the other area
>   (CI/CD). Otherwise Maven only came up when looking up Syncope.

I don't understand the scope of Apache Maven software in relation to Apache Syncope software. I thought that Syncope was strictly IAM (identity and access management) software; but, upon reading the documentation, I see that Maven is referred to in the installation guide for Syncope.

So is Maven just being used to install Syncope, or is Maven intended to work alongside Syncope and extend it's functionality?

I had already chosen Jenkins/Ansible for my CI/CD pipeline. Maven seems to overlap this functionality somehow.

My question is about how or even if to integrate Maven into my CI/CD pipeline OR Can Maven be used just to install Syncope then removed from the system? If the latter, then what, if anything, do I lose in functionality?

fwiw: I did not come into this looking for another CI/CD tool. I came into this looking for an IAM tool (and I found Syncope). When Syncope install documentation called for Maven that's when the confusion arose. If Maven would add value to my CI/CD pipeline I am not against this. But note, I wasn't looking for that when I went to the Syncope documentation.

If I can use syncope without having to deal with Maven after that it is probably best. Unless I can tell how Maven will help in the other area (CI/CD). Otherwise Maven only came up when looking up Syncope.

Thanks

> PS: I'm sorry - some clarifycation..
>
> My question is about what to do with Maven?!  I have to use Maven to get
>   Syncope? That's 1. I have to keep using Maven if I wan to use Syncope?
>   That's 2. I have to integrate Maven into my CI/CD process if I want to
>   use Syncope??? That's 3...

Comment: fwiw..  Java is not a language I know or use. I work in other langs. Just saying.

Comment: Please edit your question to ask one thing. Be more clear on what you are attempting to do and with what tool. Syncope is IAM middleware, Maven is Java project metadata, Jenkins is build and test automation, and Ansible is infrastructure automation. You may use some or all of these in your tooling (building Syncope from source) and delivery processes (deploying Jenkins for your software pipeline, using Ansible).

Comment: I appreciate that. I know my question may have been a bit unclear but I honestly don't know how to reword it any better. I think what you answered is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry - some clarifycation..

Comment: Original Post was edited for clarification. I hope it helps.